# TypeGraphQl, how to avoid definition repetitions

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Suppose I have some types

```
@ObjectType({ description: "The some other object X ..." })
export class ObjectX{
  @Field(()=> ID)
  id: string;

  @Field() 
  @Property() 
  fieldX1: typeX1;

  ... 

  @Field() 
  @Property() 
  fieldXn: typeXn; 
}
```

Now I'd like to NOT write code like ...

```
@InputType() 
export class CreateObjectX {
  @Field() 
  @Property() 
  fieldX1: typeX1;

  ... 

  @Field() 
  @Property() 
  fieldXn: typeXn; 
}

@InputType() 
export class UpdateObjectX {
  @Field(()=> ID)
  id: string;
  
  @Field({nullable:true}) 
  @Property() 
  fieldX1: typeX1;

  ... 

  @Field({nullable:true}) 
  @Property() 
  fieldXn: typeXn; 
}
```

Instead I'd want a function that takes any ClassType similar to "ObjectX", and returns 2 derived InputTypes.

- The first "CreateObjectX" omits the "id", but extends all other fields, properties and validation defined in "ObjectX".
- The second "UpdateObjectX requires "id" and extends all other fields, properties and validation defined in "ObjectX" as optional.

Such that I obtain the following schema.gql ...

```
type ObjectX { 
  id: ID! 
  x1: typeX1! 
  ...:
  xn: typeXn!
}

input CreateObjectX {
  // id: ID!  id would be omitted. 
  x1: typeX1! 
  ... 
  xn: typeXn! 
} 

input UpdateObjectX { 
  id: ID! 
  x1?: typeX1 // would be nullable
  ... 
  xn?: typeXn // would be nullable
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: This is a super useful question but I think it's better to ask on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Mixin classes are an answer to your question:
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/v1.1.1/examples/mixin-classes

Comment: Can we have multiple mixins applied to a single class? For example a User *withId & withPassword*? Thanks

Comment: Yes of course, that's the whole purpose of mixins classes that you can compose multiple ones, instead of inheriting a single class

Comment: I don't see how mixins would solve the `nullable` fields for the Update input. In the example the amend and create both have non-nullable fields.